# How to disable asp listitem checkbox via Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, forms, properties

I have the asp controls setup as follows:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="toppingsCheckBoxList">
                        <asp:ListItem type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="pickles" class="toppings">pickles</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="lettuce" class="toppings">lettuce</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="tomato" class="toppings">tomato</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="none" ID="none">none</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

And have been trying to disable the checkboxes via Jquery the way I have in the past with standard HTML controls, however it is not working quite as easily with asp controls.

here is my effort so far:

```
//Jquery for topping disabling/enabling
            $(document).ready(function () {
                //disable toppings when none is selected
                $('#none').click(function () {
                    if ($("#none").selector) {
                        $(".toppings").prop("disabled", true);
                    }else
                        $(".toppings").prop("disabled", false);
                });
                //disable none when a topping is selected
                $(".toppings").click(function () {
                    $(".toppings").each(function (index, element) {
                        if (element.selector && !$("#none").selector) {
                            $("#none").prop("disabled", true);
                        }
                    });
                });
                //enable none when no topping is selected
                $(".toppings").click(function () {
                    var count = 0;
                    $(".toppings").each(function (index, element) {
                        if (!element.selector && index in [0, 1, 2]) {
                            count++;
                        }
                    });
                    if (count == 3) {
                        $("#none").prop("disabled", false);
                    }
                });
            });
```

As you can see I have figured out that I can change .checked into .selector to see what has been checked, but for actually changing the listitem checkboxes to disabled by class name is proving difficult, I am probably just missing the simple solution though, as I am not very experienced with asp.net.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I misunderstood your question. It's actually very simple:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('input:checkbox').click(function () {
         if ($('#none').is(':checked')) {
             $('.toppings').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
         } else {
             $('.toppings').removeAttr('disabled');
         }
         if ($('.toppings').is(':checked')) {
             $('#none').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
         } else {
             $('#none').removeAttr('disabled');
         }
     });
 });
```

[FIDDLE IT](http://jsfiddle.net/tquzS/)

Comment: It seems to be working fine with the #none id, as if I put an alert in that if block it triggers when I check the box. However none of the other boxes are being disabled like they should be.

Comment: this behavior works perfectly, as did my previous implementation -- When I use input tags. However, I need to use the asp:ListItem tags so that I can do some server side validation. Is there no way to mimic this functionality when using asp controls??

Comment: the input tags should be what the HTML ASP.net is creating. what is the actual output when you view the page source?

Comment: My requirements changed, and thus your solution actually is more concise and faster running than mine, also good tip on looking at the actual source, can't believe I didn't just do that! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm about to leave work so I don't have enough time to try this out but you could try this as a guide to how you can implement it:

```
$('#none').on("change", function () {
    if($('#none').attr("disabled") == false){
        $(".toppings").attr("disabled", true);
    }
    else
        $(".toppings").attr("disabled", false);
});
```

Comment: that solution for detecting the change works, but so did my current implementation of the .selector property, I am successfully getting into the if block, but cannot disable the asp listitem checkboxes with my current method. Thanks

Comment: So I just realized that with asp there is no "disabled" property there is 'Enabled' so its not recognizing the property.

Comment: changing it to `if ($("#none").selector) {
                        $(".toppings").attr("Enabled", false);` still does nothing in the way of disabling the control ):